# Javascript: how to sort array by object value in that array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want sort a Array in JavaScript by value of object which is that array holding.

For example:

> Input

```
arr = [{id:[2, 'second']},{id:[8, 'eighth']},{id:[1, 'first']}];
```

> My excepted output is:

```
sorted_arr = [{id:[8, 'eighth']},{id:[1, 'first']},{id:[2, 'second']}];
```

Note: Please give sort by alphabet

Comment: `arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id[0] - b.id[0];
});` Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vzeqoseu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a compare function like this which will do as require.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return a["id"][0]-b["id"][0];
});
```

Suppose in case when both id's are equal, in that case if you want to do sorting on basis of your second parameter i.e first,second third then the code will be

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a["id"][0]===b["id"][0])
    {   

        if(a["id"][1] < b["id"][1]) return -1;
        if(a["id"][1] > b["id"][1]) return 1;
        return 0;

    }
    return a["id"][0]-b["id"][0];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

```js
arr = [{
  id: [2, 'second']
}, {
  id: [4, 'fourth']
}, {
  id: [1, 'first']
}];

var sort = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.id[0] - b.id[0];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sort, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

If you want to sort based on the word in array then you need to compare the values

```js
arr = [{
  id: [2, 'second']
}, {
  id: [4, 'fourth']
}, {
  id: [1, 'first']
}];

var sort = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.id[1] > b.id[1]) return 1;
  if (a.id[1] < b.id[1]) return -1;
  return 0;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sort, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```